# how to combine two 'count' value from different tables (2 column, NOT union)

Tags: sql, count, multi-table, combiners

I want to get the count of addmited records by user in 2 table. for example, I have a list of users(table STF) and want to know how many product did a user create (in table PV1) and how many product did he sell (in table dpq), I want to show these data like below:
[image]

I have these 2 queries, and don't know how to show them in one table with 3 columns...

Query 1:

```
select staff_username,  COUNT(*)  as 'count 1'
from STF right join PV1 on STF.staff_username = PV1.admit_user
group by staff_username, staff_name + ' ' + staff_family
```

Query 2:

```
select trf_staff_id, COUNT(trf_staff_id)
from dpq join stf on trf_staff_id = stf.staff_username
group by trf_staff_id
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: I edited my question, i hope i could give enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try joining two queries like this. From limited info which you have provided it seems that staff_username is same as trf_staff_id as you have used it in join condition of second query.

```
SELECT
    staff_username,
    count_1,
    count_2 FROM
    (
        SELECT
            staff_username,
            COUNT(*) AS count_1
        FROM
            STF
        RIGHT JOIN
            PV1
        ON
            STF.staff_username = PV1.admit_user
        GROUP BY
            staff_username,
            staff_name + ' ' + staff_family ) QRY_CNT_1 INNEER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            trf_staff_id,
            COUNT(trf_staff_id) AS count_2
        FROM
            dpq
        JOIN
            stf
        ON
            trf_staff_id = stf.staff_username
        GROUP BY
            trf_staff_id ) QRY_CNT_2 ON
    QRY_CNT_2.trf_staff_id = QRY_CNT_1.staff_username
```

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to combine two table `count`,You could `join` and add `count`

but you give us less information so I'm not sure.

```
SELECT
    STF.staff_username,
    STF.Data_in_PV1,
    dpq.Data_in_dpq
FROM
(
    SELECT
        staff_username,
        COUNT(PV1.admit_user) AS 'Data_in_PV1'
    FROM
        STF
    RIGHT JOIN
        PV1
    ON
        STF.staff_username = PV1.admit_user
    GROUP BY
        staff_username
) STF 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        dpq.trf_staff_id,
        COUNT(trf_staff_id) AS 'Data_in_dpq'
    FROM
        dpq
    INNER JOIN
        stf
    ON
        dpq.trf_staff_id = stf.staff_username
    GROUP BY
        dpq.trf_staff_id 
) dpq ON dpq.trf_staff_id = STF.staff_username
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to show these "count"s separately in 2 columns, on is from dpq and another is in pv1

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your table?

Comment: I guess you need to `join` tables and show their counts.